# jquery check if mouse is over element

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a "kind of" menu i created, that when your mouse is over one element the  element get different background and another element shows up.
i need both elements go back to the origin state only if the mouse is not over the first element and second element.

how can i check if the mouse is also no over the second element?

this is what i have:

```
<div class="container header-gallery">
    <ul class="col-sm-2 header-gallery-box">
        <li class="header-gallery-ico-box" data-tabId="tab-a">
            <a href=""><img src="images/gallery-learn.png" class="header-gallery-ico"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="header-gallery-ico-box" data-tabId="tab-b">
            <a href=""><img src="images/gallery-speak.png" class="header-gallery-ico"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="header-gallery-ico-box" data-tabId="tab-c">
            <a href=""><img src="images/gallery-read.png" class="header-gallery-ico"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="header-gallery-ico-box" data-tabId="tab-d">
            <a href=""><img src="images/gallery-write.png" class="header-gallery-ico"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="col-sm-4" style="height:720px; padding:0;" >
        <div id="tab-a" class="header-gallery-tab">
            <h2>Learn</h2>
            <p>
                From Middle English...
            </p>
            <h6 style="float:right;"><a href="">Read more...</a></h6>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-b" class="header-gallery-tab">
            <h2>Speak</h2>
            <p>
                From Middle English speken...
            </p>
            <h6 style="float:right;"><a href="">Read more...</a></h6>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-c" class="header-gallery-tab">
            <h2>Read</h2>
            <p>
                From Middle English reden...
            </p>
            <h6 style="float:right;"><a href="">Read more...</a></h6>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-d" class="header-gallery-tab">
            <h2>Write</h2>
            <p>
                From Middle English
            </p>
            <h6 style="float:right;"><a href="">Read more...</a></h6>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <a href="#section2"><img src="images/downArrow.png" style="width:60px; height:60px; text-align:center; bottom:-30px; position:absolute;"></a>
```

```
$(function(){
    $('.header-gallery-ico-box').on('mouseover',function(){
        var tabId = $(this).attr('data-tabId');
        $(this).css({"background-color":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)"});
        $('#' + tabId).delay(10).fadeIn(30);
    });
    $('.header-gallery-ico-box').on('mouseleave',function(){
        var tabId = $(this).attr('data-tabId');
        $(this).css({"background-color":"transparent"});
        $('#' + tabId).hide();
    });

});
```

Comment: where is you `html`

Comment: You should rethink your HTML markup to make targeted DIVs as children of relevant parent and use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover`. As a side note, you could find it interesting in your case: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
if ($('#element:hover').length != 0) {
    // do something
}
```

use it accordingly

Or use `is()` like:

```
var isHovered = $('#elem').is(":hover"); // returns true or false
```

Comment: thats the new code, but now it dosnt hide the elemnts $('.header-gallery-ico-box').on('mouseleave',function(){ var tabId = $(this).attr('data-tabId'); var isHovered = $('#' + tabId).is(":hover");

        if (isHovered==true){
            $(this).css({"background-color":"transparent"});
            $('#' + tabId).hide();
        }
    });